# working with Threadpool

Tags: c#, threadpool

Its a follow up of this question.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12260170/how-to-make-a-threadpool-to-be-nonblocking

I have achieved it using interface. I have made it nonblocking using Action/deleages & using interfaces.. Is there any other way available in .net that I can make the below piece of code nonblocking??? Interface implementation is below. At any point of time I should have only three functions Main, FuncA & FuncB

if some one could kindly help. it will be really appreciated. Thank you.

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    public interface IOperation
    {
        void CallBack(int i);
    }

    public class FuncBCalculation
    {
        public int N { get { return _n; } }
        private int _n;

        public int MyValue { get; set; }
        public FuncBCalculation(int n)
        {
            _n = n;
        }

        // Wrapper method for use with thread pool.
        public void FuncB(object context)
        {
            IOperation FuncBcallback = (IOperation)context;
            Thread.Sleep(5);
            MyValue = _n + 2;
            FuncBcallback.CallBack(MyValue);
        }
    }

    public class ActualClass : IOperation
    {
        int Finalvalue = 0;
        public static IOperation MainThreadCallBack { get; set; }

        public void FuncA(int input, int i, IOperation callback)
        {
            input += 1;
            var f = new FuncBCalculation(input);
            MainThreadCallBack = callback;
            IOperation op = new ActualClass();
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(f.FuncB, op);

        }

        //Method for callback operation
        public void CallBack(int i)
        {
            Finalvalue = i + 3;
            if (MainThreadCallBack != null)
                MainThreadCallBack.CallBack(Finalvalue);
        }
    }


    public class ThreadPoolExample : IOperation
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            ActualClass actualCall;
            const int TotalLoopCount = 1000;
            int input = 11;
            Console.WriteLine("launching {0} tasks...", TotalLoopCount);
            for (int i = 0; i < TotalLoopCount; i++)
            {
                IOperation op = new ThreadPoolExample();
                actualCall = new ActualClass();
                actualCall.FuncA(input, i, op);
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        //Method for callback operation for the main thread
        public void CallBack(int i)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The final Result is {0}", i);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: You still have to define 'non-blocking'. And try to provide a somewhat realistic uses-case and/or description. The previous was closed for good reasons. Note that it can be re-opened after improvement.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make a Threadpool to be nonblocking?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12260170/how-to-make-a-threadpool-to-be-nonblocking)

Comment: @HenkHolterman - You can see my previous post that usage of waitone..! am making a threading operation but the FuncA gets blocked until FuncB process the result & in FuncA am doing some operation based on the reult & then I am sending it back to the main thread. with the help of Marc Gravell we manged to remove the blocking using Action/delegates/interfaces. I am looking for a way in .net is that still possible to make it nonblocking. do u know any way pls let me know. Thank you.!

Comment: @HenkHolterman - its not a duplicate, its actually a follow up.

Comment: You can start making it non-blocking by removing `Thread.Sleep`

Comment: @spender - Tanx..yup...you're right..for now the code I have posted is already nonblocking (u remove the sleep-it becomes 100% non blocking) to my knowledge I know the following are the ways we can implementing threadpool in a nonblocking fashion - Action/Delegates/Interfaces..what am looking for is there a way othere than this to make it non blocking?

Comment: Found the solution - Tweek the AsyncResult class we will be able to achieve the result...Link :                                 http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/rmcochran/multithreadasyncwebservice05262007094719am/multithreadasyncwebservice.aspx

Comment: You're looking for a third way to write the same code?  Why?

Comment: @bmm6o - am working on finding all the possible ways of making a threadpool code nonblocking...!!do U know still there is anyother way to make it nonblocking..!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class State
{
    public int input { get; set; }
    public int result { get; set; }
    //public static int ThreadCount { get; set; }
    public bool FuncBSignalON { get; set; }
    //public static bool FuncAThreadON { get; set; }
   //public int TotalLoopCount { get; set; }
    //public int ThreadID { get; set; }
}


public class MainClass
{
    public static void FuncB(Object stateObject)
    {
        State state = stateObject as State;
        state.input += 2;
        state.FuncBSignalON = true;
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(FuncA), state);
    }

    public static void FuncA(Object stateObject)
    {
        State state = (State)stateObject;
        if (!state.FuncBSignalON)
        {
            state.input += 1;
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(FuncB), state);
        }
        else
        {
            state.result = state.input + 3;
            //FinalResult.Add(state.result);
            string[] stateResult = new string[1];
            stateResult[0] = state.result.ToString();
            //State.ThreadCount--;
            Main(stateResult);
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        if (args.Count() == 0)
        {
            int TotalLoopCount =1000; 
            for (int i = 0; i < TotalLoopCount; i++)
            {
                State FuncAstate = new State();
                FuncAstate.input = 11;
                //FuncAstate.TotalLoopCount = TotalLoopCount;
                //State.ThreadCount++;
                ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(FuncA), FuncAstate);
            }
        }
        else
        {
          Console.WriteLine(args[0]);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

}
```

Got it at last.

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve it something like this:

```
class _Program
{
    public static int MyInput { get; set; }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int input = 11;
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000 ; i++)
        {
            MyInput = input + 1;
            FuncA(delegate(IAsyncResult result)
            {
                AsyncResult<Int32> funcBResult = result as AsyncResult<Int32>;
                Int32 value = funcBResult.EndInvoke() + 3;
                Console.WriteLine("Final value: " + value);
            }, null); ; // using callback method
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static IAsyncResult FuncA(AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
    {
        AsyncResult<Int32> result = new AsyncResult<int>(callback, state);
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(FuncB, result);
        return result;
    }

    public static void FuncB(Object asyncResult)
    {
        AsyncResult<Int32> result = asyncResult as AsyncResult<Int32>;
        try
        {
            Int32 value = MyInput + 2;
            result.SetAsCompleted(false, value);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            result.SetAsCompleted(false, ex);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Does any one have any more solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Found another answer, but the issue is there is a chance here that the order might get confused. First, add 1 then add 2 in `FuncB`, then add 3 in `FuncA` again! Can anyone correct me?

```
public class MainClass
{
    public static List<int> finalResult = new List<int>();

    public static void FuncB(Object stateObject)
    {
            State state = stateObject as State;
            state.result += 2;
            MainClass.finalResult.Add(state.result);
            State.ThreadCount--;
    }

    public static void FuncA(Object stateObject)
    {
        State state = (State)stateObject;
        state.input += 1;
        State.ThreadCount++;
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(FuncB), state);
        state.result = state.input + 3;
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        int TotalLoopCount = 1000;

        for (int i = 0; i < TotalLoopCount; i++)
        {
            State FuncAstate = new State();
            FuncAstate.input = 11;
            FuncA(FuncAstate);
        }

        while (State.ThreadCount > 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Waiting for all the threads to terminate. Still {0} no of threads available in memory", State.ThreadCount);
            State.ThreadCount--;
            continue;
        }


       for (int i = 0; i < MainClass.finalResult.Count(); i++)
       {
              Console.WriteLine("The final Result {0}", MainClass.finalResult[i]);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();

    }
}
public class State
    {
        //public ManualResetEvent eventWaitHandle { get; set; }
        public int input { get; set; }
        public int result { get; set; }
        public int ThreadID { get; set; }
        //public ThreadStart threadState { get; set; }
        public static int ThreadCount { get; set; }
    }
```